# Windows Phone 8 sendGridMessage Compile error

Tags: c#, email, azure, windows-phone-8, sendgrid

```
   private async void sendMail(string from,string to, string subject,string text)
    {     
        // Create network credentials to access your SendGrid account
        string username = "xx";
        string pswd = "xx";

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd);
        // Create the email object first, then add the properties.
        // Create the email object first, then add the properties.
        SendGridMessage myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo("xx");
        myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library";
        myMessage.Text = "Hello World!";
        myMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);

        // Create an Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new SendGrid.Web(credentials );

        // Send the email.

        await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
   }
```

My application is Windows Phone 8.1, I try to send mail via sendGrid I created an account and include libraries to code but it gives 3 error:

1. error CS0570: 'SendGrid.SendGridMessage.From' is not supported by the language
2. error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'SendGrid.Web.Web(string)' has some invalid arguments
3. error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.NetworkCredential' to 'string'

I have used this site"https://azure.microsoft.com/tr-tr/documentation/articles/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email/" as reference.

Do errors stem from because app is a Windows Phone app or what?

And is there any other way to send an email by declaring "from" within code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but it's important enough I made it an answer and not a comment.

This is not a secure way to send email from a mobile device, because you are giving the code that contains the credentials to users that install. All they need to do is inspect the traffic from your app and your SendGrid API key or account is compromised.

You need to make a request to some secure backend server (or provider, e.g. Parse or Azure), and then send the email from that server rather than the client app.

If you want to debug the code though, check out the readme and example on Github. Microsoft's docs go out of date rather quickly. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

Comment: Thank you for your guiding answer. Actually I have tried to send email via Azure but it was only working when I have changed data(insert, update...) on table.But I will search for backend server thanks. Then I have another question: can user get my Azure account from this code within App.xaml.cs:  
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
      "",""  );  
Is it safe to store important datas within app without using credentials,web classes?